# How many bases can a vector space have?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Hello guys I am currently taking a linear Algebra class; I stumbled upon this question:

How many bases can a vector space have? Are they unique?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the base field is infinite and the dimension of the vector space is $> 0$, then there are infinitely many bases. If the base field is finite and the dimension of the vector space is $< \infty$, then there are finitely many bases. They are almost never unique, though they are for $1$-dimensional vector spaces over the field with two elements.

Comment: If you are beginning in linear algebra, you are probably thinking in vector spaces over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. Then the answer is that there are infinitely many bases. But there are finite fields. Counting how many bases has $\Bbb F_7^5$ sounds like a quite nice combinatorial problem.

Comment: thanks guys it; please go easy on me hh

Comment: @ajotatxe A well known combinatorial problem whose solution is $\frac{1}{n!}(q^n - 1)(q^n - q) \dots (q^n - q^{n - 1})$ bases for $\mathbf{F}_q^n$.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very interesting question.

It depends on the base field, but let's assume you have a (normed) real vector space.

If it's $\mathbb R^2$ then there are many, many possible bases. For example $\langle (x,0),(0,y):x,y \in \mathbb R, xy \neq 0\rangle $ are all possible sets of basis vectors.  The full set of basis vectors is $\langle (a,b),(c,d):ad-bc \neq 0\rangle$.

A more interesting question is: what does the set of all bases "look like"?

If you consider the set of all ordered bases, i.e. you think of orientation so that $\langle (1,0),(0,1)\rangle$ is different to $\langle (0,1),(1,0) \rangle$ then the set of all bases for a two dimensional real vector space $\langle (a,b),(c,d):ad-bc \neq 0\rangle$ is just $\mathbb R^4$, but with the surface $ad-bc = 0$ cut out.

What if you consider the set of orthonormal bases of $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. basis vectors have unit length and are mutually perpendicular. You can start with the standard basis: 
$$\langle (1,0,\ldots,0),(0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots,(0,\ldots,0,1,0),(0,\ldots,0,1)\rangle$$ Any new orthonormal basis can be made a linear transformation for which angles and lengths are preserved. If angles and lengths are preserved then it will still have unit vectors that are mutually perpendicular. The set of all linear transformations that preserves angles and lengths is called the [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) and denoted by $\mathrm O(n)$.

The orthogonal group $\mathrm O(n)$ is a [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space) [Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) of dimension $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$.

In the case of all orthonormal bases of $\mathbb R^2$ we get $\mathrm{O}(2)$ which has dimension $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot(2-1) = 1$.

In the case of all orthonormal bases of $\mathbb R^3$ we get $\mathrm{O}(3)$ which has dimension $\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3\cdot(3-1) = 3$.

The topology or "shape" of these spaces is very interesting. In the case of $\mathbb R^2$, the set of all sets of bases $\mathrm{O}(2)$ is two disjoint circles $S^1 \times \{-1,1\}$. To go from the standard basis $\langle (1,0),(0,1)\rangle$ to any other orthonormal basis might take a simple rotation or first a reflection and then a rotation.

Comment: This sort of beauty is what got me into mathematics. The question is very interesting indeed! How could people close it down...?

Comment: So the Lie groups $O(n)$, in some sense, act as "classifying spaces" for the set of all bases? And these Lie groups do have very interesting topology (in my opinion). For one, they're not simply connected!

Comment: They classify all orthonormal bases, i.e. ones where the basis vectors are all unit length and are mutually perpendicular, because they preserve lengths and angles. If you pick one orthonormal basis then there's a bijection between $\mathrm O(n)$ and they set of all orthonormal basis, where your chosen basis corresponds to the identity in $\mathrm O(n)$. The classifying space for all bases would be the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Every nonzero number is a basis for the one dimensional real vector space $\mathbb{R}$.

(To be precise, every set $\{a\}$ with $ a \ne 0$ ...)

Comment: To be even nitpickingly precise, a basis is not a set, but a family ;)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm puzzled. I think a basis is a set of vectors such that ...

Comment: technically we use the term "family "more than "set"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen To be technically correct, everything is a set, and sets can only have other sets as elements, and the only set with no elements is the empty set (ZFC set theory). So a basis _is_ a set =)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In my experience, a "family" has a parameter space. For example, the family of all unoriented lines $ax+by=0$ would have $(a:b) \in \mathbb{RP}^1$ as its parameter and $\mathbb{RP}^1$ would be the parameter space. For hyperplanes $a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=0$, the parameter is $(a_1: \ldots :a_n)$ in the parameter space $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$.

In my answer above, $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ would be the parameter space which parameterises the family of bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take the vectorial space $\mathbb R $,

$(1) $ is a base.
$(2) $ is a base.

$(\pi) $ is a base.
if $x\ne 0$, $(x) $ is a base since the dimension is one.

if the dimension is $N $, then each family $(u_1,u_2,...u_N) $ which is span and free is a base.